# How to unpair a Magic Trackpad 2 from Macbook and use only over USB?

Tags: bluetooth, magic-trackpad

I am using a Magic Trackpad 2 with a KVM, over USB, which seems to work fine, the Trackpad controlling the cursor only on the active computer. However, if I turn on the Macbook Pro's Bluetooth, when I switch to the other computer, *both* computers are getting the Trackpad's feed (so both cursors move, and clicks go to both). I can see this on the laptop's screen, when the cursor moves off the shared display.

I use Bluetooth for other devices, so I'd prefer to leave it on, but there is no option in the Bluetooth control panel to "Unpair" or "Disconnect" the Magic Trackpad, as there is for other devices (such as my phone). Currently, turning off Bluetooth on the MBP is the only solution I've found.

Is there a way to stop the MBP from pairing with the Magic Trackpad (or, in this case, to *unpair* them -- permanently)?

Comment: In **System Preferences** > **Bluetooth** when you hover over the Trackpad, does a circle with an X appear? That should open a dialog box to remove the device?

Comment: @agarza, the "X" appears for the Magic Trackpad 2 only if the device is powered off. As soon as I turn it on (even connected to USB), it repairs, with no "X".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can remove the pairing and then plug in the device. For as long as it remains connected, Bluetooth will pair but won’t connect.

Should it become disconnected, plug in again and it’s wired again. If you disable iCloud, the pairing won’t sync to all devices.

Comment: Can you describe the process, @bmike? The only way I've found to remove the pairing is to switch off the device — then I can use "Remove Device" in the Bluetooth pref panel — but then it doesn't work over USB either! As soon as switched back on, it automatically re-pairs with the Macbook (if the computer's BT is on). This is while it is connected over USB the whole time. (It's never been on and not cabled.)

Comment: I would power off the accessory and disconnect. Then try to delete the pairing.

Comment: I have switched the Trackpad off and deleted the device, unplugged the USB, then plugged it back in to USB. When I turn the power on, there is immediately a notification that the Trackpad has wirelessly connected — no prompt, no way to remove it. So it does not seem that it's true that "For as long as it remains connected, Bluetooth won’t pair." :-(

Comment: I'm wondering if resetting the Bluetooth module is the last resort in this situation. In Catalina, you would Shift+Opt click the Bluetooth icon in the menubar then select **Reset the Bluetooth module**. In Monterey, I believe this is no longer valid; I am looking to see what is the equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @agarza! (I didn't know about Shift+Opt — seems to work on many of the menu bar status items.) But yeah, no Reset option shows up in Monterey. If you find anything else, please let me/us know!

Comment: I’ve changed the won’t pair wording. It absolutely pairs @big_m but doesn’t connect until you disconnect USB. You should see the connect animation when you disconnect the wired connection that takes precedence over Bluetooth.

Comment: Ha. Well, I guess you are right, though I remained baffled by Apple's implementation. I turned off the device, removed it from the Bluetooth panel (turns out, the "X" appears when the device is off or out of range), then turned it back on while connected over USB (same as before). Again, I immediately see the "Your trackpad is wireless connected to this Mac." message (no asking if I want to) — but _this time_, when I switch to the other computer, the Macbook cursor freezes and trackpad taps are not received on the Macbook. So, success! I just wish I understood what was different this time! :-/